# Can I chart OHLC or candlesticks with WPF System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, charts, .net-4.5, wpftoolkit

I need quick and dirty OHLC or candlestick chart in WPF app.. 
Can I use System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting for that? is there a jumpstart example on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF Toolkit doesn't have such charts out of the box, but you can try to search some custom implementations. For example, this implementation can be what you need: [Candlestick Based off WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/294704/Candlestick-based-off-WPF-Toolkit)

Also a similar question was already asked, you can look at it as well: [For WPF, FREE candlestick example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834144/for-wpf-free-candlestick-example)

Comment: am gonna try the codeproject solution thanks.. P.S. the SO link you gave is nothing to do with System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting